# CanGrow property does not work

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports, line, records

I have a field that contain data with more than one line. I`m using VS 2010 and crystal report. The property CanGrow work fine in all records except last record it appear in one line. Look at the picture below.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your field `Normal Value` is growing - we can see two lines. Maybe your surroundig box ist not respecting that increase in height.

Try checking `Extend to Bottom of Section when printing` of your surroundig box. Right-click your box, then select `Format Box`:

[image: Format Box]